# Rendering Crispy Form + no submit button

Tags: django, django-crispy-forms

I trying to use crispy layout for my form. 
I have followed instruction and tutorial but because I am new to Django and python I got lost and it does not render my form as well as submit button.

I have model form defined:

```
class nowyPhForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Phandlowy
        fields = ('imie', 'nazwisko', 'email', 'telefon', 'firma', 'filia')

        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            super(nowyPhform, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.helper = FormHelper()
            self.helper.form_method = 'post'
            self.helper.form_action = 'submit_survey'
            self.helper.add_input(Submit('submit', 'Submit'))
            self.helper.layout = Layout(
                Row(
                    Column('imie', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                    Column('nawisko', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                    css_class='form-row'
                ),
                Row(
                    Column('email', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                    Column('telefon', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                    css_class='form-row'
                ),
                Row(
                    Column('firma', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                    Column('filia', css_class='form-group col-md-6 mb-0'),
                    css_class='form-row'
                ),
                Submit('submit', 'Sign in')
            )
```

and HTML

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}

  <div class="container">
    {% crispy form %}
  </div>

{% endblock %}
```

I would appreciate if someone could spot problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the submit button manually as follows. Following snippet will render your form.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .forms import nowyPhForm

def view(request):
    form = nowyPhForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = nowyPhForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('some_other_url')
    return render(request,'template.html',{'form':form})
```

template.html

```
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
    <form method="POST">
       {% csrf_token %}
       {{ form | crispy }}
       <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
</div>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Hi, thank you for looking at this issue. According to article linked below. Crispy can also render button. See last example in the article. https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2018/11/28/advanced-form-rendering-with-django-crispy-forms.html

Comment: You use the wrong tags. It should be 
{{ form|crispy }}

Comment: It should be {{ form|crispy }}

Comment: Also you need to add csrf token

Comment: Yes @YasinUğur right, thanks for pointing. Going to edit it.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me (in template.html):

```
{% crispy form form.helper %}
```